# Check if one specific line exists in a file?

Tags: ruby

I want to add the following line to ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH
```

But only if it doesn't exist.

How could I check whether that line already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This-ish, maybe?

```
File.open(".bashrc").each_line do |line|
    if (line == "foo")
        return true
    end
end
return false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
path_seen = false
File.open( ~/.bashrc ) do |f|
     f.grep( /export PATH:\/var\/lib\/gems\/1.9.1\/bin:\$PATHg/ ) do |line|
       path_seen = true
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since carriage returns are in short supply in this day and age...

```
return File.open('.bashrc').lines.any? { |line| line.chomp == 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question probably meant to say:

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH
```

(note the first ':' should have been an '=')

Also, when creating regular expressions with many '/'s (as per @ennuikiller's solution) you might like to use the %r{} literal constructor rather than //. For example:

```
f.grep( /export PATH:\/var\/lib\/gems\/1.9.1\/bin:\$PATHg/ ) do |line|
```

becomes the easier to read (with minor correction - removal of the trailing 'g'):

```
f.grep( %r{export PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:\$PATH} ) do |line|
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question looking to check if a specific Rails route was already present:

```
route = "mount Blorgh::Engine"
File.open('config/routes.rb').each_line.any? {|line| line[/#{route}/] }
```